# excel spreadsheet average with prioritization

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help how to write excel formula (or any excel solution)
to sum with priorities.

I have transaction data like this:

```
Date  Unit  Price  Buy/Sell 
7/11   3     10     Buy 
7/12   2      9     Sell
7/13   4      8     Buy 
7/14   3     11     Sell
```

I want to calculate average buy price for units in hand not for all bought units.
I had 2 units in hand, recall FIFO, so the average will be $8.

3 units @$10 and 4 units @$8 bought, and the first 5 units were sold .

Any ideas to solve this problem in excel?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this with worksheet functions, because you have to keep track of an arbitrary-length list of buy prices, which changes over time.

Under the assumption that the number of units is a positive integer, I can do it with a helper column. Let's say the data is in columns A-D and the helper column is E.

In E2, put
`=IF(D2="Buy",E1&REPT(C2&",",B2),MID(E1,1+FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(E1,",","*",B2)),32767))`

Then at the end the final cell will contain a text string that you need to turn into an `=AVERAGE()` formula using one of the methods in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Unfortunately, you're likely to run into the cell length limit which is 32768 characters.